# Advice required for data quality and validation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

**FURTHER EDIT:  Given that individuals can only access the questionnaire from a seperate website, not internal on their LAN/ WAN - I'm thinking all I can do is have a link for each group of people and simply limit that to the number in the group, not control the issue of 10 individual responses or 1 person doing it 10 times...**

EDIT: Imagine a scenario where there is 1 pc - 10 people need to complete the questionnaire, all from the same PC.  We cannot contact the 10 people, we have no means of doing so.  We need to ensure (as much as possible) that there are only 10 responses and, ideally, they are done by the 10 individuals, not 1 person doing it 10 times!**

This is more general advice needed than a specific answer to a question - however, I'm still hopeful you guys can help.

Currently we have a short questionnaire that we need to ensure that is only completed once by each person to ensure data validity.

We cannot email each individual a unique link to the questionnaire as they do not have email addresses.

In addition, we also need to control the number of responses to the questionnaire from each group of people (for example a group of 10 cannot have 11 responses).

Does anyone have any advice on how this might be achieved without sending unique links to individuals?

Note, technology in use is MySQL, PHP, Javascript (some jQuery and a very small amount of Ajax).

Thanks in advance,

Homer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is virtually impossible to uniquely identify a specific user at 100% absolute certainty.

The user can always remove cookies, change his IP address, clear cache and localStorage.

Theoretically the user may fill in the questionnaire and format his computer, to fill it again.

The real question here, where do you compromise? You can always set a cookie, and comparing it against his IP address in the database, does it guarantee he can't bypass it? No, it can't. How malicious are your users? Will they try to scam the system?

Another possibility is require an account made for each user filling in the questionnaire, but again, nothing prevents a user from opening multiple accounts.

Comment: Yup, appreciate that - I guess I'm looking at the 'best possible' solution as opposed to the perfect solution!

Comment: The best possible solution would be to make users register an account, and using a combination of sessions, cookies and the user's IP address. However, as stated in the question above, if your users are malicious enough, even that will fail.

Comment: Yep, appreciate that - not looking for a 'perfect' solution as there isn't one just looking for 'best fit' cheers for the feedback.

Comment: Given your edit, it is impossible to distinguish between people. The program can, maybe, distinguish between PCs, but it cannot tell who sits in the front. (It can, but that's way beyond your problem). So the only advice I can give you is to distinguish the group as best as possible, and limit the number of times it can be filled on the server side. Whether one user fills it 10 times or 10 users fill it 1 time, you cannot tell.

Comment: Looking more and more like this - the only option I have is whether there is any login at PC level that people need to do - if there is I might be able to piggy back on that?

Comment: Even if there is, this is not PHP's realm. @Homer_J

Answer (score 1):

one question: how are you identifying unique individuals?

either, they have some identifier in the url they are accessing, or they log in to the system in order to take the survey.

i think you should have a table in your database that records each participant, and whether they have taken the survey.  then check this when they are logging in, and allow them to proceed when appropriate.

Comment: Hi Randy, we do have this but for this particular questionnaire we can't use it as we won't have this information.  If that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

When do you consider a person as **unique** ?

You could identify people by setting a cookie - but then, what happens when the user clean the cookie? what happens when the user moves to another computer?

What if 2 people complete the same questionnaire from the same computer?

Comment: This is exactly the problem we have - imagine 1 computer, 10 people need to complete it from the same PC - we cannot contact them or speak with them - how could it be done (accept there are limitations here)?

Comment: simply put - you can't - unless you have a crystal globe or some sort of device to read the mind of the one that completes your questionnaire

Answer (score 0):

You would need some kind of unique identifier per person filling out the questionnaire, could be an email address (although you say the people don't have an email address? Is it for kids to fill out or something?) or name, address, postcode. Without a dataset I can't really help that much.

Or if you know that this is going to be filled out by people in different households, then I guess you could use the IP address as a unique identifier (but this isn't ideal, nor do I recommend it).

Comment: IP address isn't a goes, all from same IP.

Comment: Hmmm okay, in that case, what information are you able to capture during the questionnaire that you could use to identify if this is a unique participant or not? Is there anything? e.g. Name/postcode/email?

Comment: Fair question - the information that we could collect is an 'employee number' however, this is not appropriate to collect for confidentiality reasons!  We could ask for job role.

Comment: Wouldn't there be multiple people with the same Job Role? I suppose you could always use that along with some other information that is captured, perhaps the sex and age of the participant? It would be unlikely (although still possible) that someone with the same job title is the same sex and age as another participant.

Answer (score 0):

Generate unique line of parameters for each user, something like:

```
group=5&user=[GUID]
```

encrypt these parameters with algorythm + urlencode result

this way you'll get encrypted unique url for user, which you can pass to him.

```
qn.php?hdfs78376897923874987
```

Once get on page urldecode/decrypt parameters. Keep in database result - from what group is answer, if this person already answered etc

Comment: Thanks for this - this is how we do it currently.  The issue here is we have no contact with the individual - we cannot pass that to him.

Answer (score 0):

Starting question: How do you ascertain the identity of a person? How do you group these identities?

Next: Are you on a single network? Are these users in a single network domain like your office or company LAN? Are they random people from the internet or passers-by?

If, for example, your users are registered in your active directory, you can use:

http://alpho011.hubpages.com/hub/Use-Windows-Login-in-PHP-Applications

As for grouping, continuing from the example above, you can also access their object properties and see if you can group in that direction like the object property "manager" or "department"

If your users come from different locations and are not bound by VPN connections, then you can look into storing IP addresses.. but depending on the questionnaire and the type of users your application is up against, this might not do.

Limiting a user to a one-time-submission without identities is quit tricky. Perhaps you can give us more information?

Comment: OK, all people are on a LAN/WAN - however they'll be accessing the questionnaire externally via a seperate website.  No access to directory of users etc.  Limiting via IP won't work as the IP is the same for all.

Comment: I just read your /further edit/ section... So do you mean that you're going to give up on controlling whether or not a single or 10 separate persons fill your survey? If so, then one group-code based link per pc(or group) seems like the way to go for you...

Comment: The effort required to control on an individual basis, in this scenario, looks to not be worth it.  So, it might well be we simply control at group level on this occasion.